# ASP.NET MVC How to get allowed users? in windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, windows-authentication

I have web config:

```
<location allowOverride="true" path="Admin/Secure">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="SpecificUserName1" />
        <allow users="SpecificUserName2" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I need to get all users (SpecificUserName1, SpecificUserName2) in runtime.
How can i accomplish this?

**UPDATE** I need to do this in View

Now i use default approach:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
 //secure menu
}
```

**Now:**
Menu showing for all users in domain, but access granted only users which exists in web.config

**Need:**
Hide menu/allow access for all users in domain except users which exists in web.config

**UPDATE**

I found the solution
http://forums.asp.net/t/1787320.aspx/1

```
UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, HttpContext.Current.User, HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first, **don't use `web.config` to control authorization in an ASP.NET MVC application**.

Use the [`[Authorize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute. Decorate the corresponding controller/action with it:

```
[Authorize(Users = "SpecificUserName1, SpecificUserName2")]
public ActionResult Secure()
{
    ...
}
```

You could then externalize those usernames in a constant and reuse the value. By the way depending on where exactly you need those values, there might be other ways to retrieve them.

Comment: I don't use forms authorization i use windows authorization, your answer complitely wrong!!!

Comment: The Authorize attribute has nothing to do with Forms Authentcation. It perfectly fine works with Windows Authentication as well. Your comment is completely wrong. **Never**, and I repeat, **never** use the web.config to control authorization in an ASP.NET MVC application. No matter which authentication scheme you are using - Windows or Forms or a custom. The very single day someone changes the route pattern in your Global.asax and forgets to update the path of the location element in your web.config your site gets open to anyone :-)

Comment: Oh and by the way I very strongly invite you to read some getting started tutorials about ASP.NET MVC Windows authentication: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs Especially when you are implementing a secure web site with authentication. This way you won't fall into an embarrassing situation later. And yet another tutorial for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Autorize work with forms authentification http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs , and many other links

Comment: Authorize works with **any** authentication. Not just forms. Windows as well. And even with custom authentication. That's the beauty of it. You configure the authorization scheme in web.config and then control the authorization by using the Authorize attribute, no matter how your routes are setup. You could of course do it the older, classic WebForms way, I just don't recommend you to do so since you are developing an ASP.NET MVC application. For me it was just important to point that out so that other people having the same problem as you don't make the same mistake if they see this question.

Comment: Why does it show secure admin menu in @if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { }  is specify access in location section

Comment: Request.IsAuthenticated means that there's an authenticated user accessing the site. That's always the case when you are using Windows Authentication (otherwise you wound't even have seen the controller action being executed and the web server would have rejected the request much before it even reached the view). If you need to restrict the menu only to certain groups of users you could use the `@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) { ... }` check inside your view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18055/discussion-between-testcoder-and-darin-dimitrov)